# Conversion API integration, centralized solution?

Tags: android, ios, api, rest

Problems to be solved: Currently, we have to build Conversion API integration for every single partner (facebook, google, other programmatic...) which is not scalable as it burns too much resources for platform integration 1 by 1.

I'm working on a marketing tech project that is trying to build a centralized place to postback conversion data via API (aka server to server integration).

Wondering if there are any API or marketing experts that have idea of building a centralized API so it easier to integrate/monitor conversion API in one place?

Any advice, article reads are welcome!
Thank you all